# Data type mismatch when retrieving records from an access database using a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetimepicker

I get a Data type mismatch criteria expression error when i try to retrieve records from an access database between two dates using a DateTimePicker in C#.

This is the Select statement

```
else if (dtpDOBFrom.Value < dtpDOBTo.Value)
{
    cmdSearch.CommandText = "SELECT [First Name], [Surname], [Contact Type], [Birthdate] FROM [Contacts] WHERE [Birthdate] >= '" + dtpDOBFrom.Value +"' AND [Birthdate] <= '" + dtpDOBTo.Value +"'";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dtpDOBFrom.Value` is a DateTime, which you are trying to paste into a string. Thus, the DateTime is converted into a string, but the format seems to be different from the format that Access expects. You could play with the parameters of `DateTime.ToString` (and enclose the date in `#` instead of `'`, since this is what Access wants), but that would **not** be the right way to do it.

The right way, which avoids such type cast problems in general (and SQL injection, among other things), is to use [parameters](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access):

In your case, it would look something like this (untested):

```
cmdSearch.CommandText = "SELECT [First Name], [Surname], [Contact Type], [Birthdate] FROM [Contacts] WHERE [Birthdate] >= ? AND [Birthdate] <= ?";
cmdSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOBFrom", dtpDOBFrom.Value);
cmdSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOBTo", dtpDOBTo.Value);
```

With OLEDB (which is used for MS Access database access), the name of the parameters ("DOBFrom") is not important, but the order in which you add them must match the order of the question marks in the SQL.

Comment: Thank very much :)
It worked, I'll remember to use parameters in the future

Comment: I did try the ToString() as well, but that also didn't work ...  But your solution was just what I was looking for.